# How to give a ModalBottomSheet a margin?

Tags: flutter

[image]

If I give the ModalBottomSheet a horizontal margin, the margin on the left and right is different.

Why are the right and left margins applied differently?

Here is my code.

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              builder: (context) {
                return Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  // I applied the same left and right margins 
                  // with the horizontal property, 
                  // but when I look at the screen,
                  // the left and right margins are different.
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Text('text'),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text('show bottom modal'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the code you share and the code from the image are same? I can't seem to reproduce it with the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EdgeInsets` to achieve consistent left and right margins:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.black,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),  //add this line
              child: Text('text'),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: Text('show bottom modal'),
    ),
   ),
 );
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Not work. I tried replacing symmetric with only, but it's the same.

Comment: It is working in my case.